# Changing event target

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have following html:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

If mouse is clicked on div2, then `e.target` is div2. I want target to be div1 in this case. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is. It's also _much_ easier with a supporting library like jQuery.

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Do you need to trigger an event for `div1` or modify `div1` in some way?

Comment: try using e.target.parentElement to get div1

Comment: I'm getting attribute of e.target, depending on that attribute I decide I can do some action or not (div1 has that attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to walk upward up the DOM tree until you find the element you want.

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {

    // start with the element that was clicked.
    var parent = e.target;

    // loop while a parent exists, and it's not yet what we are looking for.
    while (parent && parent.id !== 'div1') {

        // We didn't find anything yet, so snag the next parent.
        parent = parent.parentElement;
    }

    // When the loop exits, we either found the element we want,
    // or we ran out of parents.
    console.log(parent);
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7kYJn/

Comment: Thanks Alex, your answer was very useful

Answer (score 1):

In DOM, you can specify which element to attach the event listener to:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
div1.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
   console.log(e.target);
});
```

Comment: Nice decision, but i have multiple divs like div1 and this is not useful in my case. Big thanks anyway

Comment: But if "live" style event delegation is desired, this won't work. If you want to bind one handler, and then add a dozen `#div1`'s to the page, this will fail to handle the clicks.